# FactoryGirl - is it possible to define a factory that will create only one instance and always return that one instance?

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

Say I have this in multiple specs...

```
let(:thing){FactoryGirl.create(:thing)}
```

...is there a way to set up the factory such that the first time it's used to  create a *Thing* it creates it, but the 2nd and following time it's used, it returns the instance it created on the first call?

Comment: Although you could theoretically do `let(:thing) { Thing.first || FactoryGirl.create(:thing)} ` In practice you shouldn't need to do that because referencing `thing` multiple times within a test will not re-execute the block, and referencing `thing` in different tests will by default be operating on an empty database.